# SQL -> Обратиться к столбцу по форматированному названию

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы.

1. `users`, где есть столбец `rank` с форматом `int`
2. `fractions`, в котором перечислены названия рангов с названиями столбцов типа: `rank1, rank2, rank3 .. rank15`.

Вопрос такой. Как я могу получить название ранга из таблицы `fractions`, имея число-номер ранга в таблице `users`?

`SELECT users.rank, f.rank + users.rank FROM users LEFT JOIN fractions AS f ON users.member = f.id`

Comment: Использование данных как метаданных возможно только в рамках динамического SQL (prepared statement).

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял какая у тебя структура таблицы f, то вот:
SELECT f.rank FROM f WHERE f.id=(SELECT users.rank FROM users)

Comment: Не подходит данный вариант